# Sails-Mongo - Retrieve all populated data from DB on querying

Tags: mongodb, associations, sails.js, waterline

I am new to Sails. I have two models User.js and Project.js. ProjectMember.js is the model that links both of the models.
User.js

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    userName: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    company: {
        type: 'string',
    },
    password: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    passwordSalt: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: 'datetime',
        defaultsTo: null
    },
    projects: {
        collection: 'ProjectMember',
        via: 'user'
    }
  }
}
```

Project.js

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    company: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    members: {
        collection: 'ProjectMember',
        via: 'project',
        dominant: true
    }
 }
}
```

ProjectMember.js

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

    project: {
        model: 'Project'
    },
    user: {
        model: 'User'
    },
    projectRole: {
        model: 'ProjectRole'
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: 'datetime',
        defaultsTo: null
    }
 }
}
```

I want to retrieve data from Project model in such a way that it also retrieves the associated models/collections from the other models. Is there any method to do so, other than moving through all the models like this:

```
        Project.find({
            id: projectID
        }).populate('members').exec(function (err, results) {
            async.each(results, function (result, error) {
                if (err) {
                    retObj.type = "failure";
                    retObj.message = "Error in getting user list";
                    callback(retObj);
                } else {
                    var ids = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.members.length; i++) {
                        User.findOne({
                            id: result.members[i].user
                        }, function (err, resp) {
                            var userObject = new Object();
                            userObject.userID = resp.id;
                            if (err) {
                                retObj.type = "failure";
                                retObj.message = "Error in getting user list";
                                callback(retObj);
                            } else {
                                userObject.company = resp.company;
                                userObject.email = resp.email;
                                userObject.userName = resp.userName;
                                ids.push(userObject);
                                if (ids.length == result.members.length) {
                                    callback(ids);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/256

Comment: I tried using the method given in https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/256. But it said, "attempting to populate an attribute that doesn't exist.
Is it possible to call a model like:


        User.findOne({
            email: 'abc@abc.com'
        }).populate(['projects',
            'projects.project'
        ]).exec(function (err, doc) {
            res.send( doc );
        });

Comment: sorry, the links intent was to show you that what you want current is not possible, but their are others with this issue and that was the discussion being generated around it